# Python: EOFError using cPickle while running a class instance

Tags: python, python-2.7, pickle

This is the code snippet causing the problem:

```
if str(sys.argv[2]) + '.pickle' in os.listdir(os.curdir): #os.path.isfile(str(sys.argv[2]) + '.pickle'):
            path = sys.argv[2] + '.pickle'
            #print path
            instance = cPickle.load(open(str(path)))
```

This is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                               
  File "parent_cls.py", line 92, in <module>                                                                                                
    instance = cPickle.load(open(str(path)))                                                                                                     
EOFError
```

If this keeps happening because of file.close() is not performed or some other ridiculous mistake, please let me know if there is a way to access the pickle file using subprocess. Thanks.

UPDATE: Another thing I notice. The filename.pickle to check if its there or not using the if condition actually is creating a filename.pickle although it wasn't there first.

I dont want to create it but to check its existence. is this some other problem?

Comment: Why would you want to access the file using subprocess? Are you reading/writing to that file in another part of your code before this? Also you don't need all those `str` functions: you are already working with strings.`open` opens the file in read mode by default, so if the file is created should be elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Yes R/W could be in another part of the code.. Yes I know str is stringing the already stringized thing.

Comment: @Salem would subprocess.Popen(open(path), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=None, stdin=None) be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Open it in binary mode :

```
 open(str(path), 'rb')
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                               
  File "parent_cls.py", line 92, in <module>                                                                                                
    instance = cPickle.load(open(path, 'rb'))                                                                                                    
EOFError